# UIView is resets to initial value after presenting other view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, core-graphics, calayer

UIView's frame and position properties reset to initial value after presenting other view controller.

```
- (IBAction)moveClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    self.imvOriginal.center = CGPointMake(self.imvOriginal.center.x + 200, self.imvOriginal.center.y + 200);
}

- (IBAction)showClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    TopViewController *vc  = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"topViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

After topViewController is closed, imvOriginal's center property is reset automatically.
In fact, this properties is reset when topViewController is opened.

I will not use auto constraints, because I should implement move, scale, rotate of ImageView using Pan, Pinch, Rotate gestures. This features change the position, affineTransform properties of ImageView's layer.

How should I fix this problem?

Comment: So, did you turn off auto layout?

Comment: no, I didn't set the constraints to ImageView

Comment: Not setting constraints is not the same thing as turning off auto layout. The system adds constraints for you if you don't add them yourself. You need to go to the file inspector and uncheck the "Use auto layout" box if you don't want to use auto layout.

Comment: I have to use auto layout for other elements.

Comment: Auto layout is a storyboard wide setting -- it's either on or off for all views. If you want a particular view to not use constraints, you should create that view in code, and set its frame.

Comment: perfect! please post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th problem you're seeing is caused by auto layout. Even if you don't set constraints for a view, if auto layout is on (which it is by default), the system will add constraints for you. If you want to use auto layout for some of the views in your storyboard, but not for another particular view, then that view should be created in code.